# Establecer background-color a partir de un array de colores

Tags: angular-directivas, angular4

Tengo un componente que se encarga de mostrar los valores de un array de objetos y cada objeto tiene asignado una serie de colores:

```
colores: any = [
    {id: 1, c1: '#f0f0f0', c2: '#c8c8c8', c3: '#b4b4b4', c4: 'a0a0a0', c5: '8c8c8c'},
    {id: 2, c1: '#ff0ff', c2: '#ee82ee', c3: '#da70d6', c4: 'ba55d3', c5: '9370db'}
];
```

Mediante la directiva ***ngFor** estoy tratando de mostrar los colores pero no como texto, sino como el propio color, estableciéndolo como fondo de un div (en el siguiente codigo saldria el texo de cada color):

```
<div *ngFor="let color of colores">
  <div>{{color.c1}}</div>
  <div>{{color.c2}}</div>
  <div>{{color.c3}}</div>
  <div>{{color.c4}}</div>
  <div>{{color.c5}}</div>
  <hr>
</div>
```

Y estoy tratando de pasar las propiedades del objeto directamente como un **style** y veo que no funciona:

```
<div *ngFor="let color of colores">
  <div style="background: {{color.c1}}">{{color.c1}}</div>
  <div style="background: {{color.c2}}">{{color.c2}}</div>
  <div style="background: {{color.c3}}">{{color.c3}}</div>
  <div style="background: {{color.c4}}">{{color.c4}}</div>
  <div style="background: {{color.c5}}">{{color.c5}}</div>
  <hr>
</div>
```

Como puedo hacer esto de forma correcta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para hacer el binding de un estilo puedes usar la siguiente sintaxis:

```
  <div [style.propiedad-css]="valor"></div>
```

Para tu ejemplo sería lo siguiente:

```
  <div [style.background-color]="color.c1">{{color.c1}}</div>
```

[Aquí](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uyoy4s?file=app%2Fapp.component.html) te dejo un ejemplo funcionando.

> NOTA: Fíjate que en la definición del Array de colores, en algunos
>   casos se te ha olvidado poner la almohadilla `#` antes del código
>   hexadecimal del color.

Answer (score 2):

Tienes que bindearlo con la directiva ngStyle.

```
<div [style.background]="color.c1">{{ color.c1 }}</div>
```